# How to run automated ui testing for ionic appflow builds?

Tags: ionic-framework, automated-tests, github-actions, cicd, ionic-appflow

I have an Angular-ionic app, and I'm using Ionic AppFlow to push new builds to the native Android and iOS apps.

I have automated UI tests running through Cypress to test that the app loads the correct content and has the desired behavior.

Cypress requires a running development server in order to run the tests. For example you'd start ionic dev server on `http://localhost:4100/` and write the Cypress test starting from visiting the app on `http://localhost:4100`:

```
describe('Ionic app tests', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:4100');
    });

    it('test case description', () => {
        // ... test this and that
    });
});
```

In Ionic AppFlow, you'd build the app on *ionic cloud*, and push the build to mobile devices without running any development server on the cloud, therefore, according to [this](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/testing-your-app), I think Cypress isn't a suitable testing tool to test Ionic AppFlow builds.

My question to the community is - what automated UI testing tools can I use to test Ionic AppFlow builds after they are built on the cloud? Or in other words, how can I UI test my mobile app after it receives a new update through AppFlow?

Comment: You cant. Appflow does not provide that feature. you need to manually download apk and run test yourself.